# How do i get text node with XPATH contains?

Tags: python, xpath

Im trying to get text node that contains some string, but it does not return anything.
Here is the [page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7481432/).

here is the html snippet:

```
<div id="FNA_envelop">✉ Corresponding authors: Wanli Liu, Department of Clinical Laboratory, Sun Yat-sen University Cancer Center, 651 Dongfeng Road East, Guangzhou 510060, Guangdong Province, China. Telephone/Fax: +86 20 8734 3438; E-mail: <a href="mailto:dev@null" data-email="nc.gro.ccusys@lwuil" class="oemail">nc.gro.ccusys@lwuil</a>; Min Deng, Affiliated Cancer Hospital &amp; Institute of Guangzhou Medical University, No.78, Hengzhigang Road, Guangzhou 510095, P. R. China. E-mail: <a href="mailto:dev@null" data-email="moc.361@590015nimgned" class="oemail">moc.361@590015nimgned</a>.</div>
```

My xpaths:

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="FNA_envelop"]/*[contains(text(),"Deng")]')
[]
response.xpath('//div[@id="FNA_envelop"]/*[contains(.,"Deng")]')
[]
```

The idea is to get text node that contains name, then get following a tag and extract email(associated with name) from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text nodes are selected with `text()`, thus, if you really want a text node (and not an element node containing the text) then I would expect you to use or suggest to use e.g. `//div[@id="FNA_envelop"]/text()[contains(., "Deng")]` or, if the text nodes are not (only) direct child nodes of the `div` but perhaps deeper inside other child or descendant elements, to use `//div[@id="FNA_envelop"]//text()[contains(., "Deng")]`.

Comment: why should i use . instead of text() in contains part?

Comment: @BillyJhon `.` means "current node" and you've already selected the text nodes you want with "text()".

Comment: @BillyJhon, if you had e.g. `text()[contains(text(), 'foo')]` you would try to select a text node that has a text node child node containing the string `foo`. But a text node doesn't have any child nodes, it is a leaf node.